# How to handle UIApplicationDidRegisterToRemoteNoticationsWithDeviceToken outside the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, appdelegate

I am creating an iOS framework project where I want to register for Apple Push notifications.

I created a sample app and have all the required methods like `registerRemoteNotifications` in `AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingOptions` method. I already implemented the `didRegisterToRemoteNoticationsWithDeviceToken` method in AppDelegate and it gets the device token upon registration. Everything works well in the sample iOS app.

Now, how do I implement the `didRegisterToRemoteNoticationsWithDeviceToken` outside of the AppDelegate in a framework project?

For other methods like 'didFinishLaunching', I implemented it through `NSNotificationCenter` but the equivalent one for remote notifications is deprecated after iOS 8.0 (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623010-registerforremotenotifications).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(registerForPushNotifications:) name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
```

I am returning to iOS development after a long break so I am kinda lost here.

Please advise, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

Do what the FB SDK for iOS does and create a helper method that the user of the framework should **call** in the application delegate of the host app. The method should take the device token as an argument.

Example method declaration from the Facebook SDK:

```
+ (void)setPushNotificationsDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken;
```

Comment: Ohh man..! Thank you so much! So, the host app will have to implement these methods in the AppDelegate and will send over the deviceToken when it gets it to the framework. So, that means even the call -   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications] has to be done in the host app and not in the framework? Based on what is mentioned here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-notifications/ios#notifications

Comment: You welcome! You **can** call `registerForRemoteNotifications` from your framework, since it can access `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` as well. The example you linked is just a possible implementation.